# Servlet and static method

Tags: servlets, thread-safety, static-methods

can someone take away me a doubt? I've a Servlet that is called by three different parts. Each of this parts represent a different operation, but using the same servlet and with the same parameters. Now i've thinked to implement a class with three static methods that will be called adequately. I've thinked this to avoid too much code in processRequest() method. I don't use static variables! Is better to do this or put all the code in the Servlet? Thanks all.

Comment: why static methods in servlet? can't you just create private methods as needed and call them from your processRequest()?

Comment: Yes it's true. But i need to use these methods in another Servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please avoid `static methods` in servlets simply create `Normal java class` and put all your bussiness logic as
`Different functions`.Whenever and Where ever you wanted those functions call them using objects of that class.Because Calling static method  or method of a `servlet` from another `servlet` is not good idea.

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: whenever you wish to have some kind of logic which does some work with args,but no instance creation this is the better idea because if same logic need to be applied you can easily get with out redundant code and performance is good.